# Does Inkscape have a smooth tool like the one found in Illustrator?

Tags: inkscape

I just want to know where the smooth tool might be in Inkscape or if it has similar tool to smooth strokes AFTER they are put down.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. No it doesn't have a smooth tool, but there are methods to smooth lines, such as the Simplify LPE effect. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

The node tool has in the info bar button "Make selected nodes auto-smooth" An example:

[image]

The upper 2 curves are the originals. The lower ones are their duplicates. Both of them were selected by dragging over them with the node tool and auto-smoothing button was pressed.